AG Charts - apply linear gradient to area chart fill
Is it possible to set the fill of an area chart series in ag-charts-react to a linear gradient? I am not able to find an example of this in the docs or anywhere else.
I tried searching through the AG Charts docs, as well as a broader Google search. The answers ChatGPT and Copilot gave me did not work either.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
